# How should I organize a large JavaScript dialog object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a very large JavaScript object I'm using to store RPG dialog, containing several large top-level objects. The dialog is formatted similar to JSON.

1. When organizing the dialog, should I put each of those top level categories in their own function?
2. Or maybe their own separate javascript file?
3. Does keeping all the text in one javascript (`var json =`) object affect performance?

Any organization tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Use whichever way makes for the cleanest code. Optimize as you encounter bottlenecks. Don't worry about it until that time.

Comment: @meagar thanks for the post edit; sometimes I get carried away with my question and forget to simplify it.

Comment: Is this about JSON or JavaScript now? Those two are different things. Firs you mention JSON, then JavaScript files and JavaScript objects. Please be clear about your question.

Comment: @Growler Never use 5 paragraphs where a single sentence will suffice :)

Comment: @FelixKling It's about how to best organize JSON within the context of JavaScript. I also had that small question if putting them all in one JS object would have a performance hit.

Comment: I had a look at your original question with the code. It didn't contain any JSON, only a JavaScript object. So it seems to me that your question is more about JS objects than JSON (they are different things). Especially as there is no such thing as a "JSON function".

Comment: @FelixKling Does it matter if I store text as such in a JS variable similar to the format of JSON versus actually storing the JSON as a JSON text file then parsing it?

Comment: Maybe not, but describing your problem using JSON and JS object interchangeably is rather confusing.

Comment: @FelixKling Noted. I edited the question above accordingly. But, what are your thoughts on storing JSON in a JS variable versus as actual to-be-parsed JSON.txt file? What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should generally try to limit coupling whenever possible.  Therefore it would make sense to separate these into separate functions, but see point #3 about databases.
2. You can separate them into separate javascript files if it gets too big to manage easily with one.  You can always have a build process that lumps them all together later (check the [html5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) for more on this technique).
3. It probably isn't going to make much difference for performance at this point.  I might suggest using something like [mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) in the future as you get more data though.  Take a look at [meteor js](http://www.meteor.com/) to get some inspiration.  Using a database can simplify your code if you do it right.

Comment: Mentioning Meteor JS smacks of spam. How is that even tangentially related to organizing a JSON file? The server-side datastore is 100% irrelevant here.

Comment: I have no association with meteor.  I just think that it is a good example of going a step beyond storing all your data as a JSON file.

Comment: @meagar I disagree with "smacks of spam". Can we not give one another the benefit of the doubt on occasion so that we might help OP without fear of accusation? 
There is plenty of other content to this answer I don't know why you have singled out a link that is almost an afterthought to the rest.

Comment: @DrewR I didn't flag as spam, or downvote; I *am* giving jmh the benefit of the doubt. I still fail to see how this is relevant. It's just like saying "Oh by the way, you should consider using ASP.Net". **Totally** irrelevant. Name-dropping unrelated frameworks when we're talking about how to organize plain old JSON data.

Comment: @meagar I appreciate your points. I just disagree that it is totally irrelevant. Maybe slightly tangential but not irrelevant. jmh suggests using MongoDB rather than storing flat JSON files and in my interpretation cites meteor as a demonstration of the code simplification it allows whether agreeable to me or not. IMO suggestion of an alternative approach with evidence of its benefits is as valid as suggesting a solution to the problem.

Comment: When somebody asks questions as general as this, I think maybe they are looking for something above just "how do I solve this particular problem."  So I suggested an approach that may scale better than his current approach.  If I was writing an RPG using javascript, I would want to use a DB like mongodb to organize my data.  Meteor is a project that uses mongodb and I thought it was a good example of binding data between client/server.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing question 1, this sounds like JSONP? Slightly different. 
I would suggest that performance differences would be negligible for parsing though if using JSONP and injecting `<script/>` elements to the DOM file size becomes a factor, and it would be wise to group related data into seperate files so that it can be retrieved selectively.

Obviously at the top level if not using JSONP, you can seperate your objects into an array or one keyed object.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your question before the edit and to me it wasn't *only about JSON*. I understand the reasoning behind meagar's edit but I don't agree with it. I think you should really step out of the technical details and focus on what your data **is**. You are writing the story of your game in a JSON file. Is that really appropriate or convenient? I personally don't think so. I mean, if you're comfortable working with this so far, sure, knock yourself out. Myself, I would use plain and simple text files to hold that dialog (1 line in a file = 1 line of dialog, with name of file = name of NPC or cutscene) They're much more appropriate for storytelling IMHO.

What I mean is, write that dialog in something that is meant for writing. JSON is a format for data-interchange, sure, it's *human-readable*. That doesn't mean it should be *human-written*.

**Then**, when you have your story, if you want your game to consume that data in JSON form, write some kind of wrapper around this bunch of files. Sure, it looks like more work, but I think it's more flexible. Well, that's what I would do anyway. Best of luck.